# 12.10 screen resolution on Acer Aspire S3

Tags: 12.10, resolution, screen, acer

I'm new to Linux and recently installed 12.10 alongside Windows on my laptop.

Initially 3D screen effects (i.e., Docky) were not working and I tried different things like installing and reinstalling `nvidia-current`, `compiz`, etc...

Now, I think I messed up the display drivers completely. Although all the effects are now working, I can't get any screen resolution other than 640x480.

Can anyone please tell me how to find out exactly what's wrong and ways of fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, I figured it out myself. In case someone encounters this problem, I'll outline the solution which helped me.

1. I removed nvidia-current since the videocard on this notebook is Intel:

   `sudo apt-get --purge remove nvidia-current`
2. Changed the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file:

   `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Modeline       "1366x768_59.90"  106.29  1366 1520 1672 1904  768 901 904 932  -HSync +Vsync
    Option         "PreferredMode" "1366x768_59.90"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Modes "1366x768_59.90"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The key was placing "intel" driver over there, this might actually be enough, but I also added the resolution myself which finally did it for me.